# Directional derivative exists does not imply total differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, polar-coordinates, differential

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{x^3}{x^2+y^2},\text{if $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$}\\ 0,\text{if $(x,y)=(0,0)$}\end{cases}$

Show that for every $v=(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ the directional derivative $D_vf(0,0)$ of $f$ exists in the point $(0,0)$, but $f$ is not totally differentiable.

So, I calculate the directional derivative easily by:

$D_vf(x,y)=\lim_{t\to 0\\ t\neq 0}\dfrac{1}{t}\left(f(tx,ty)-f(0,0)\right)$

$=\lim_{t\to 0\\ t\neq 0}\dfrac{1}{t}\left(\dfrac{t^3x^3}{t^2x^2+t^2y^2}\right)=\dfrac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$ as $t$ just cancels out.

But how do I show that $f$ is not totally differentiable?

I want to test for total differentiability in $(0,0)$.

When I calculate the derivative we get:

$\dfrac{3x^2(x^2+y^2)-2x^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}-\dfrac{2yx^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=\dfrac{3x^2(x^2+y^2)-2x^4-2yx^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Plugging everything in the formula:

$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)\\ (x,y)\neq (0,0)}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\left(\dfrac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}-\dfrac{3x^2(x^2+y^2)-2x^4-2yx^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right)$

Now I use polar coordinates: $x=r\sin(\varphi)$ and $y=r\cos(\varphi)$, and get:

$\lim_{r\to 0} \sin^3(\varphi)-3\dfrac{\sin^2(\varphi)}{r^3}-\dfrac{\sin^4(\varphi)-2\cos(\varphi)\sin(\varphi)}{r}$

But this limit does not exist, and in particular is not $0$.

So $f$ would not be totally differentiable in $(0,0)$.

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f$ was differentiable at $(0,0)$, then, for each $v\in\Bbb R^2$, $f'(0,0)(v)=D_vf(0,0)$. But that's impossible, since the map $v\mapsto D_vf(0,0)$ is simply $f$, which is not linear.

Comment: How simple and elegant!

Comment: Very nice indeed!

Comment: Why is $D_vf(0,0)=f$? If we use the formula $D_vf(0,0)=Df(0,0)v$, I do not see why this is $f$? Forgive me, I am a little bit tired at the moment...

Comment: Well… that's what you got, right?! I mean,$$D_vf(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}=f(x,y).$$

Comment: Oh, excuse me. Yes, maybe I should take a break. I was focused on my calculation of the partial derivative, and forgot about that result....

Answer (score 1):

For the differential, you should compute
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-xD_1f(0,0)-yD_2f(0,0)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
where $D_1$ and $D_2$ are partial derivatives.

According to your calculations, $D_1f(0,0)=1$ and $D_2f(0,0)=0$, so $f$ would be differentiable at the origin iff $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0.$$

But, in this case,
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{-xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}$$
so taking the directional limit when $y=x$, you'll get that the limit cannot be 0.

Comment: How do you get $xD_1f(0,0)$ and so on? My formula says that I have to look at $L(x-x_0)$ ($L$ the linear function of course) where $x_0$ is the point in question. Thats why I took $x_0=(0,0)$ to make it simpler, but then I would have $-xD_1f(x,y)-yD_2f(0,0)$. Besides that, is my calculation correct, or simply wrong?

Comment: First, in your case $x_0$ is teh origin. Morever, $L(x)=\nabla f\cdot (x,y)$.

Comment: Yes, but isnt that what I have written?

Comment: $L(x)=\nabla f(x_0)\cdot x$. The gradient should be particularized at the point you're studying.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: I just revisited this answer, and I am actually confused. You write "According to your calculations $D_1f(0,0)=1$ and $D_2f(0,0)=0$" but I never calculated these?? When I calculate the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and I look at the limit $(x,y)\to 0$, which I think I have, right? Then I get $D_1f(0,0)=0$. What am I missing?

Comment: You get $D_vf(0,0)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$ where $v=(x,y)$. $D_1=D_{(1,0)}$ and $D_2=D_{(0,1)}$. You do NOT write in this way, but you indeed DO this calculations.

Comment: Thank you very much. Of course, the partial derivatives are just the directional derivatives for the basis vectors...